# Average every 20 numbers in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, average

I have an a large array ( +400 numbers) `decimal[] Raw` where I need to average every 20 numbers, send those numbers to a new array, or list `RawAvgList`,
then form a new array, or list to get that average of the numbers in `RawAvgList`.  Aka my code should find the average of the first 20 numbers and stores them in my new array/list, then next 20, then next 20. It should also for count if there are more or less then 20 number at the end of the large array

Should my while loop be in another loop that restarts the counting index??
Should I just be removing every 20 numbers as I go? I know just simply using the `Average()` on the `decimal[] Raw` is an option but the numbers needs to be more exact then that function can give. I have also tried using `IndexRange` but when the number isn't divisible by my count (20) it give and error, which will happen.

I have just been stumped for so long I am at my wits end and frustrated beyond belief, anything to help.

```
int unitof = 20;

decimal[] Raw = new decimal[] { Decimal.Parse(line.Substring(9).ToString(), style1) };

for (int i = 0; i < Raw.Length; i++)
{ 
    while (count < Raw.Count()) 
    {
        RawAvgList.Add(// ** Average of every 20 numbers **//);
        count += unitof; // 20 by 20 counter
    }

   // Reset counter or add another counter?? 
}
```

Edit (8/22/2022)

I added the IEnumerable<IEnumerable> Chunk as suggested, but I believe something else went wrong or I didn't fully understand how it worked because i have never used chunks.

I implemented the Chunk

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Chunk<T>(this IEnumerable<T> values, int chunkSize)
{
    return values
    .Select((v, i) => new { v, groupIndex = i / chunkSize })
                .GroupBy(x => x.groupIndex)
                .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.v));
}
```

added what you suggested

```
var rawAvgList = Raw.Chunk(20).Select(chunk => chunk.Average()).ToArray();
var result = rawAvgList.Average();
```

and then tried printing to the Console.Writeline()

```
Console.WriteLine($"{result} \t " + LengthRaw++);
```

Which got me and output of

```
36.41    0
37.94    1
38.35    2
37.63    3
36.41    4
36.41    5
36.21    6
36.82    7
37.43    8
37.43    9
37.43    10
37.43    11
37.43    12
37.94    13
37.94    14
37.84    15
37.43    16
37.84    17
37.43    18
37.84    19
37.84    20
```

When the output should be ( I am only using 21 numbers at the moment but it will be more then that later)

```
37.37    0 
37.84    1
```

Comment: _"I know just simply using the Average() on the decimal[] Raw is an option but the numbers needs to be more exact then that function can give"_ What does that mean? `Enumerable.Average` is exact. It's simply adding all decimals and then dividing through count.([source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,40cbe9769247429e,references)).

Comment: I know but doing averages of averages was the way they wanted it otherwise I would just be doing the Average() function.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Enumerable.Chunk()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.chunk?view=net-6.0) to split the data into batches of at most 20, and then average all those chunks:

```
decimal[] raw = new decimal[10000]; // Fill with your data.,

var rawAvgList = raw.Chunk(20).Select(chunk => chunk.Average()).ToArray();
var result = rawAvgList.Average();
```

However I don't know what you meant by

> It should also for count if there are more or less then 20 number at
> the end of the large array

The last block which will be averaged will be less than 20 long if the input is not a multiple of 20 items long, but all other blocks will be exactly 20 long.

Comment: _"If you don't need to store the intermediary results..."_ then OP could simply use `raw.Average()`. The question is why OP didn't want to use that method(_"needs to be more exact then that function"_).

Comment: @TimSchmelter Good point, I've removed that bit (although there may be tiny differences just caused by rounding errors)

Comment: I added your suggestion to my code but I am still getting stuck. All my data appears but its not averaging every 20 numbers. I have edited my question to show. Thank you for your help!!! @MatthewWatson

Comment: @MidnightBlueKnight I'm not sure what you're actually doing wrong because you didn't post a compilable repro - [but here it is working correctly](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OvnS7P).

Comment: @MatthewWatson okay I see why mine isn't working. I am calling my numbers, for the raw array, from a text document, and I just have the for loop iterations wrong. Would it be smart to convert it to a double array from a decimal array? The numbers are stored as string and in Scientific Notation(3.743e+1).

Comment: @MidnightBlueKnight It should be OK to keep it as Decimal, but it really depends on what you need.